# Geany doesn't print a few combination of characters

Tags: editor, geany

I just got Geany 1.36 and everything was working fine until I tried to type a **"-"**. It turns out Geany doesn't print characters like **"."** , **"-"**  , **"<"**, **","**. I have to type an extra character to get it to show. It seems like it stores it in a buffer and when I type an extra character it prints both characters at once.

Also, character combinations like (**.** + **s**), (**.** + **r**), (**.** + **t**) doesn't print at all.

I changed the font settings, (can this be the reason?) but then I reinstalled Geany again and I still have this issue.

(I cleaned the preference files from APPDATA too)
I searched the entire net, even looked through Geany manual but couldn't find anything.

If you know anything about this do let me know.

I am running Windows 10 and Geany 1.36.

Comment: It's possible that some autocompletion bit is flaky in the Windows version (Can't test myself; I'm running Linux). Try unchecking the various autocompletion options in `Edit > Preferences > Editor > Completions` and see if that helps.

Comment: I just tried that, but it is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU programs don't work properly if the keyboard layout is not set up correctly.
Make you sure you set up the keyboard layout correctly, for the majority of the people it should be EN-US
Search for **Edit keyboard and layout options** and make sure it is set up to EN-US (or whatever the correct one is)